# Azure functions - How to access HttpRequest data in a class other than function

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a Http triggered azure function and I am injecting a custom attribute 'api' using 
***IExtensionConfigProvider***

```
 public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext exeContext, [Inject(typeof(Api))]Api api)
```

Below is the code for config extension

```
 public class InjectConfiguration : IExtensionConfigProvider
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        RegisterServices(services);
        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);


        context
            .AddBindingRule<InjectAttribute>()
            .BindToInput<dynamic>(i => _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(i.Type));
    }
    private void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var conifg = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();

        services.AddTransient(api =>
        {
            return new Api(config["ApiUrl"]);
        });


    }
}
```

I want to use a different configuration setting here `return new Api(config["ApiUrl"]);` based on the input received in the request. For ex -  logically it should be -

```
  services.AddTransient(api =>
        {
           // If in http request query string value is A then
            return new Api(config["ApiUrl"]);
           // If the value is B then
            return new Api(config["ApiUrl_New"]);
        });
```

How can I access the HTTP request data in there? or let's say how can I access HttpRequest data in my 'Api' class?

Comment: I believe you can't. IMO it's a good thing in this case, you should resolve it in function body.

Comment: I am injecting a Http Client as an attribute because I want to unit test my function using a mock http client. In real, the Url this client calls come from config and I want a conditional load of that config setting.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve, but my opinion is that DI resolution shouldn't use HTTP request. Instead, you should resolve into something stable and then e.g. accept request as a parameter to make the final decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

Borrow from the [HttpContextAccessor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs) and set the HttpRequestData in a Middleware.

```
public class HttpRequestDataMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var triggerType = context.FunctionDefinition.InputBindings.Values.First(a => a.Type.EndsWith("Trigger")).Type;

        if (triggerType == TriggerTypes.HttpTrigger)
        {
            var requestData = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();

            var accessor = context.InstanceServices.GetRequiredService<HttpRequestDataAccessor>();
            accessor.HttpRequestData = requestData;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class HttpRequestDataAccessor
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<HttpRequestDataHolder> Context = new();

    public HttpRequestData HttpRequestData
    {
        get => Context.Value?.HttpRequestData ?? throw new Exception("Attempting to access the request data before it is set");
        set
        {
            var holder = Context.Value;
            if (holder != null)
            {
                // Clear current HttpContext trapped in the AsyncLocals, as its done.
                holder.HttpRequestData = null;
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                // Use an object indirection to hold the HttpContext in the AsyncLocal,
                // so it can be cleared in all ExecutionContexts when its cleared.
                Context.Value = new HttpRequestDataHolder { HttpRequestData = value };
            }
        }
    }

    private sealed class HttpRequestDataHolder
    {
        public HttpRequestData? HttpRequestData;
    }
}
```

```
services.AddSingleton<HttpRequestDataAccessor>();
```